# All indices being antisymmetric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I was wondering how one does expand the following?
$$\delta^{[a}_{[c}\delta^{b]}_{d]}$$
is it like: 
$$\delta^{[a}_{[c}\delta^{b]}_{d]}=\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{[a}_{c}\delta^{b]}_{d}-\delta^{[a}_{d}\delta^{b]}_{c})+\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{a}_{[c}\delta^{b}_{d]}-\delta^{b}_{[c}\delta^{a}_{d]})$$
or
$$\delta^{[a}_{[c}\delta^{b]}_{d]}=\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{[a}_{c}\delta^{b]}_{d}-\delta^{[a}_{d}\delta^{b]}_{c})\times\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{a}_{[c}\delta^{b}_{d]}-\delta^{b}_{[c}\delta^{a}_{d]})$$
or something totally different?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think the right way is the following: 
$$\delta^{[a}_{[c}\delta^{b]}_{d]}=\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{[a}_{c}\delta^{b]}_{d}-\delta^{[a}_{d}\delta^{b]}_{c})\\=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{a}_{c}\delta^{b}_{d}-\delta^{b}_{c}\delta^{a}_{d})-\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{a}_{d}\delta^{b}_{c}-\delta^{b}_{d}\delta^{a}_{c}))\\=\frac{1}{4}(\delta^{a}_{c}\delta^{b}_{d}-\delta^{b}_{c}\delta^{a}_{d}-\delta^{a}_{d}\delta^{b}_{c}+\delta^{b}_{d}\delta^{a}_{c})\\
=\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{a}_{c}\delta^{b}_{d}-\delta^{b}_{c}\delta^{a}_{d})$$